# ¿Qué palabra se usa en España en vez de "Reservación"?

Tags: sinónimos, solicitud-de-término, españa

El otro día buscando la palabra **Reservación** llegué a la [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=W9D126w) y di con esto:

> reservación
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de reservar.
> 2. f. Am. Reserva de habitaciones, de localidades para un espectáculo, etc.

Por lo que puedo entender aquí la palabra Reservación solo se usa en América, mi pregunta es:

¿Qué palabra se usa para sustituirla en España? Ya que estuve pensando un rato y no encuentro un *Sinónimo* que haga referencia a reservar una habitación o un boleto de avión.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La palabra *reservación* sí se usa, de vez en cuando, con el significado do *acción y efecto de reservar* (si no se indica al contrario, se supone que cualquier acepción es panhispánica).

Pero en el sentido de lo que tienes tras hablar con un hotel, etcétera, en España la palabra normal es simplemente **reserva**.  Por ejemplo, primero haces una reserva y luego pagas esa reserva.

Pero has mencionado también un *boleto* de avión.  En este caso, se puede referir tanto a la *reserva* como al *billete* en la mayoría de los casos.  El billete teóricamente es la parte física, no obstante, mucha gente «pillé un billete muy barato para ir a Australia» sin tenerlo en mano.  Si vas a la mayoría de los sitios web de las líneas aéreas, se habla de gestionar la reserva, o modificarla, etc.   No obstante, son suficientemente intercambiables que para acciones como comprar, o cancelar, pues, encontrarás las dos palabras casi sin distinción ([Iberia dice](http://www.iberia.com/es/gestion-de-reservas/) comprar billetes pero cancelar reservas en la misma frase).

Comment: El billete y la reserva son cosas distintas. La frase de la web de Iberia *Comprar el billete o Cancelar las reservas hechas en iberia.com* se refiere a que si tienes una reserva sin billete emitido puedes o comprar el billete o cancelar la reserva.

Comment: @rsanchez entiendo la distinción técnica, pero en el habla cotidiana creo que la mayoría de las personas no suelen hace gran distinción. (Aunque cancelar un billete curiosamente implicaría que lo has usado, no que has decidido no viajar)